# Using clearInterval() inside Useeffect is not working. The function in setInterval() keeps getting called

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setinterval, use-effect, clearinterval

**Desired Outcome:**
I am getting a script's status from an API and then checking what the status is.
If the status = 'XYZ', I need to call the getStatus function again (using setInterval),
else I just need to return/do nothing.

**Issue:**
The major issue is that clearInterval() is not working and the getStatus() function is getting called after the mentioned interval (10 seconds here) again and again, EVEN THOUGH the status IS NOT EQUAL to 'XYZ'.

Please help out. Thanks in advance.

```
const [intervalId, setIntervalId] = useState();

useEffect(() => {
    getStatus();
  }, []);

  const getStatus = async () => {
    await getScriptStatus()()
      .then(response => {
        if (response.data[0].status == 'XYZ') {
          setIntervalId(
            setInterval(() => {
              getStatus();
            }, 10000)
          );
        }
        else
           return () => clearInterval(intervalId);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        errorMessage(error);
      });
```

**UPDATE:**
Using React.useRef() instead of useState() for intervalId and clearing interval before using setInterval() in the 'if' condition worked or me.
Thank you for the helpful answers.

Comment: In the `else` clause you are returning the arrow function, but that function isn't called anywhere. That's why the interval is not getting cleared.

Comment: Also, won't that `setIntervalId` trigger state change, new mount and in effect another `useEffect` (`getStatus`) call, effectively multiplying cascade of in-revocable intervals? (Shouldn't there be simple setTimeout for this purpose?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`intervalId` doesn't need to be a "state", rather store is as a ref and not a state.

- Notice I changed your function from using `.then().catch()` to using `async/await`.
- I think that the problem you're facing is caused because React State is asynchronous - the `setIntervalId` didn't update the `intervalId` yet, when you're trying to already access `intervalId`'s new value

```
const intervalId = useRef(null);

const getStatus = async () => {
    try {
        const response = await getScriptStatus()()
        if (response.data[0].status == 'XYZ') {
            intervalId.current = setInterval(getStatus, 10000);
        }
        else return () => clearInterval(intervalId.current);
    } catch (error) {
        errorMessage(error);
    }
}
```

Another suggestion:

The `getStatus` function should not act as a useEffect-function, because it's very confusing to see that `getStatus` returns a function.. and then you need to trail back to "AH it's a useEffect-function.. and the function returned is a cleanup function.. " - not good.. .

so.. My Suggested Options for that:

- Either change the `getState` function to only getStatus.. and then when you call it from inside the `useEffect`- also handle the case in which you want to return a function (cleanup function)
- Less suggested: Have all the content straight inside the `useEffect`. And since you want to use `async/await` -> create a self-calling-async-function: `useEffect(()=>{ (async () => { await func(); })(); }, []);`

## Update:

In addition to all that ^
You really don't need the `setInterval` (like others have suggested). `setTimeout` will do just fine. But you might still want the `clearTimeout` (changed from clearInterval) if the functio might be called on different occasions

Comment: There does not seem to be a reason for calling `clearTimeout` (and as a result to store its ID either) in provided logic; it is basically "try (something) again later (if it failed)". Since there is no other signal of "success" than decision around setTimeout, timeout is either set (in the "fail/try again" branch) or is not (in "success" branch), so there is nothing to clear. ClearTimeout would make sense only as "abort" in hypothetical scenario when next try is not needed any more.

Comment: Yeah I agree, Except there are many things I would change in the provided code-flow, so I was just think of a case of someone else calling this `getStatus` function and then he might do want to clear the timeout... But I think clearTimeout() in this case should just happen every time, at the beginng of the function

Comment: Hm, shared component and multiple concurrent "subscribers" is an interesting insight, but I think that when done properly, even there would be some kind of centralized provider (singleton) that would keep track of the state (like "pending timeout before request" | "request sent, waiting for response" | "we actually have the status already"), so cancelling timeout or aborting request would make sense only in "teardown" or so, called just once.  "Clearing [(which?) timeout] every time at the beginning" would make little sense then.

Comment: Hi @ShaniKehati 
Making a minor change in your code does the trick. We would also have to clearInterval() before we use setInterval() in the 'if' condition.

Comment: @RajAryanSharma Makes sense. Don't forget to set this as the Answer

Comment: Clearing *interval* on its first invocation, i.e. preventing its consecutive invocations and (recursively) installing another *interval* is effectively the same as using simple (recursive) *timeout* and not clearing anything.  Long-polling server *in interval* really doesn't make any sense, only introduces possibility to end up with exponentially growing amount of intervals when not cleared properly.
Single(!) *interval* should be really either installed outside `getStatus` and cleared on success, or replaced with *timeout* as suggested.

Comment: @myf We all agreed a timeout should replace the interval (:

Answer (score 2):

Use `setTimeout` instead of using `setInterval`.

For more details visit : [Documentation on setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout)

Answer (score 0):

Main problem here is most probably that you are **installing new intervals recursively**: function installs interval that calls function that installs interval etc, effectively producing cascade of intervals. These are more or less in-revocable, because their IDs live ephemerally in function scope that installed them and are then thrown away.

You can observe it with slightly modified version of your code in [this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-mccarthy-hjsk4z?file=/src/App.js).

Answer (score -1):

Change `return () => clearInterval(intervalId);` to this `clearInterval(intervalId);`.